# Store string as immutable

Tags: constructor, immutable

I want to deploy an nft contract and i want to enter URI in constructor:

```
string immutable i_uri;

constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory uri) ERC721(name,symbol)  {
    i_uri = uri;
}
```

But i got this error : `Immutable variables cannot have a non-value type.`

What is the problem?? i haven't same problem with uint,address and etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables):

> Not all types for constants and immutables are implemented at this
> time. The only supported types are strings (only for constants) and
> value types.

not implemented, use constant instead.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that constant/immutable variables have their values defined during compilation and deployment,  therefore I don't see a way to change them programmatically. Instead you could use a `private` variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Example {
    bytes private i_uri;

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, string memory uri) {
        i_uri = abi.encodePacked(uri);
    }

    function getURI() public view returns (string memory) {
        return string(i_uri);
    }
}
```

NOTE: `Imutable` is outdated,  better to use `contstant` (For solidity ^0.8.0)

Comment: I know constant but you can not define constant value in constructor, constructor must entered directly, i want to enter value programmatically.

Comment: And also i test it and it doesn't work because of constant, so i changed constant to immutable but also i got same error like string.

Comment: The issue is that the "constant" is defined during deployment, and cannot be changed later.  Therefore I think in this case, it might be best to use "private" variable instead.  (I will update my code to explain)